# IF function with multiple choices in one cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have some data which are answers to one of my question forms.

Some questions could have multiple answers. For example:

> What is your hobby?
>
> 1. Traveling
> 2. Filming
> 3. Sport
> 4. Dancing

Each answer has it's own number (as it shown above).

*i.e. 1 is for Traveling, 2 for Filming etc.*

Some of cells have multiple answers.

*For example: A3 cell has 1,3,4 inside. Numbers is separated with commas.*

In another Excel sheet I am writing the table with answers which are represented not as numbers, but as a names (words). With single answers it is easy to make by function IF:

```
IF(A1=1,"Traveling",IF(A1=2,"Filming",IF(A1=3,"Sport",IF(A1=4,"Dancing","Error"))))
```

But with multiple answers I have a problem. How to separate numbers, so Excel can understand, that cell A3 has 3 answers: Traveling(1), Sport(3) and Dancing(4)?

Comment: Should I it use with IF ir just single function SEARCH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution, with your `1,3,4` string in cell **A1** the following formula will return `Travelling,Sport,Dancing`, as required:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,1,"Travelling"),2,"Filming"),3,"Sport"),4,"Dancing")
```

Note: this method (using `SUBSTITUTE` could be repeated up to a maximum of number 9. Although I wouldn't advise this because it will become somewhat unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [SEARCH](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SEARCH-SEARCHB-functions-9ab04538-0e55-4719-a72e-b6f54513b495) like `IF(SEARCH("1",A1),"Traveling")` instead of `IF(A1=1,"Traveling")` and so on (e.g. `IF(SEARCH("3",A1),"Sport")`)

Comment: But if I A1 hasn't 1 then I got #VALUE! . Even if I have IF_False statement.

And one more question: How should I combine functions to write for example "Traveling, sport, dancing." If in cell there is 1,3,4?

Comment: And what should I do if number of answers is 13? If Cell with answers will have for example 2,13 And I will write Search(1,A1) it will find 1, because 13 has number 1.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following *User Defined Function (UDF)*:

```
Public Function MultiReturns(sIN As String) As String
    Dim i As Long

    nums = Array("1", "2", "3", "4")
    lets = Array("Traveling", "Filming", "Sport", "Dancing")

    MultiReturns = ""
    If sIN = "" Then Exit Function

    ary = Split(Replace(sIN, " ", ""), ",")

    For Each a In ary
        For i = LBound(nums) To UBound(nums)
            If a = nums(i) Then MultiReturns = MultiReturns & "," & lets(i)
        Next i
    Next a

    MultiReturns = Mid(MultiReturns, 2)
End Function
```

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as **.xlsm** rather than **.xlsx**.

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
=MultiReturns(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: For new Excel 2016, you have to Save-As, "Excel macro enabled workbook" *.xlsm.

Comment: @ejbytes  You are correct !